# Using jQuery to set Margin on child li based on parent position

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a project where we're scraping a site and pulling in the content, as a result I don't have control over the structure of the divs or lis.

The problem I'm running into is that on the menu the drop downs aren't left-aligning with the parent menu item.  I'm looking for some css/jquery that will help solve this issue, [here's a link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gQCH/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/9gQCH/3/)

**CSS & HTML**

```
    #item1, #item2 {        
       background-color:#efefef;           
       display:inline;
       font-size:14px;
       margin-right:3px; 
       padding:5px; 
    }

    .Submenu {
        display: none;
        padding: 4px; 
        margin-top:18px;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }  

    .Menu li:hover .Submenu{
        background-color:orange;
        display:inline;
        color: black;
        padding: 3px 5px;
        position:absolute;
    }



    <div class="Menu">
    <li id="item2">
        High level Item 1
        <div class="Submenu">
            <div>
                   Nested Item 1         
            </div> 
            <div>
                   Nested Item 2       
            </div>         
        </div>
    </li>  

    <li id="item2">
        High level Item 2
        <div class="Submenu">
            <div>
                   Nested Item 3         
            </div> 
            <div>
                   Nested Item 4       
            </div>         
        </div>
    </li> 
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Divs inside li's without a ul? That's some strange structure you've got there.

Comment: `DIV`s inside an `LI` are fine, but you definitely need to wrap your `LI`s in a `UL` tag. And why not use a `UL` for the submenu?

Comment: I'd love to be able to use a UL, howerver, since the page is being scrapped from another site I can't control that.

Comment: @AndrewK Ah yes, forgot about the scraping bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for this. Simply add this to your CSS:

```
.Menu li { position: relative; }
```

Update (Add `left: 0;` to your `.Submenu` class):

```
.Menu li:hover .Submenu{
    background-color:orange;
    display:inline;
    color: black;
    padding: 3px 5px;
    position:absolute;

    left:0; // <------
}
```

(You can also add a `top` property if you find it necessary)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kboucher/gbhtC/

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, I'm wanting to align the entire sub-menu to the left so it lines up to the left of the parent item, thanks.

Comment: That's what it does. What are you seeing? (Check the Fiddle)

Comment: I'm seeing the text wrap to a seocond line on the submenu but that's about it, what browser are you using, I'm on Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/9gQCH/7/

Using JQuery

```
$(".Submenu").each(function(){
    $(this).css("left",$(this).parent().offset().left);
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked too, appreciate it, going with the pure css option above, but this is a great alternative